# Java Spring Javaconfig - Expressed dependency?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

What would be equivalent in JavaConfig compared to this?:

```
<bean id="s1"
    class="lab.Some"
    depends-on="d1"
    />
<bean
    id="d1"
    class="lab.Dependable"
    />
```

I mean when writing config class with `@Configuration` annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the `@DependsOn` annotation:

```
@Bean
Some s1(){ ... }

@Bean
@DependsOn(["s1"])
Dependable d1(){ ... }
```

I have been doing a lot of Groovy so this code may not be perfect but should reflect the idea.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it should be the other way around, `s1` depends on `d1`.